# Пропадание картинки из bitmap'a

Tags: android, java

Пишу программу типа лотереи, где надо стереть первый слой и увидеть второй.
В перовм слое есть прозрачность.
Проблема в том, что когда я начинаю стирать первый слой, он сразу же пропадает.
Как исправить эту проблему?
Код:

```
paint = new Paint();
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));  
        paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        final ImageView bs = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fr);
        final ImageView srt = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dspt);
        balls.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) balls.getLayoutParams();
                Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                float dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();
                float dh = currentDisplay.getHeight();
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                srt.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        downx = event.getX();
                        downy = event.getY();
                    break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int x_cord = (int)event.getRawX();
                        int y_cord = (int)event.getRawY();

                        if (x_cord > windowwidth)
                        {x_cord = windowwidth;}
                        if (y_cord > windowheight)
                        {y_cord = windowheight;}

                        layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 35;
                        layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 35;
                        bs.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, x_cord, y_cord, paint);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        upx = event.getX();
                        upy = event.getY();
                        canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
                    break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так у Вас, вроде, картинка просто меняется первая на вторую

```
srt.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Надо отображать две картинки на одном месте - первый слой (обязательно с alpha-каналом) поверх второго. При нажатии на экран менять только alpha-канал первого слоя.

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это сделать.

Comment: Да я бы с радостью, но я ни в зуб ногой ни в Андроиде, ни во фреймворке, который Вы используете. Хотя если одна картинка отображается до onTouch - полдела сделано. Просто так же аккуратненько добавить вторую

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз за ответ, но я разобрался сам: подключил библиотеку WScratchCard